# Should numeration of a list of axioms be continued?

Tags: mathematics, writing, formatting

I have a definition like the following:

**Definition** *System of sides* is ... conforming to axioms:

1. ...
2. ...
3. ...

**Definition** *Monotone* system of sides is a system of sides conforming to additional axiom:

4. ...

**Definition** *Distributive* system of sides is a system of sides conforming to additional axiom:

5. ...

My question: Should I continue numbering of axioms as above, or should the additional axioms be numbered from one (not from four or five as above)?

Also note, that every distributive system of sides is a monotone system of sides.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about mathematical notation, not about academia. While questions about the process of research are on-topic here, questions about the specific research areas are not.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers See [this meta discussion](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/3256/a-question-about-a-typographical-arrangement).

Comment: @EnergyNumbers I strongly disagree with this assessment, per the meta question, and have voted to reopen.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend thinking about this presentation problem in the following way: if you were inclined to be verbose, it would be perfectly correct to say:

> **Definition** *Monotone system of sides* is a system of sides conforming to the axioms:
>
> 1. ...
> 2. ...
> 3. ...
> 4. ...

As such, it is not so much that you wish to *continue* a list of axioms, as it is that you wish to take advantage of the similarity of the two lists of axioms to present this information in a way that is more streamlined and easier to understand.

As such, I would recommend making the elision explicit, as in:

> **Definition** A *monotone system of sides* conforms to the same axioms 1-3 for a system of sides, plus an additional axiom:
>
> 4. ...
>
> **Definition** A *distributive system of sides* conforms to the same axioms 1-4 for a monotone system of sides, plus an additional axiom:
>
> 5. ...

Notice also that I have extended the italics to the whole statement "X system of sides," rather than just the adjective, since you are not defining e.g., "monotone" but rather "monotone system of sides."

Comment: Side question about English usage: "Plus an additional axiom" or "Plus _the_ additional axiom"? Given that the sentence introduces the axiom, I have the impression that the latter would be better. Am I wrong?

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano I have no strong opinion between the two; they are slightly different, but I personally would be comfortable with either presentation.

Comment: @Massimo Ortolano: I think "Plus *the* additional axiom" would be better, because there is only one additional axiom being talked about in the sentence. Yes, I realize there could be other axioms that would be suitable in the presence of the previous axioms, but the sentence is not referring to all (or some) such possible axioms that one could include with the previous axioms, but rather to a certain specific such axiom.

Answer (score 2):

If you can give the axioms reasonable names, then you could use those instead of numbers.  The LaTeX environment for doing this is called "description".  You already have good names for the last two axioms, namely "monotone" and "distributive", so it remains to check whether your axioms 1, 2, and 3 can be given good names.

Answer (score 0):

I think this if fine. But you could also label them differently:

```
A *system of sides* complies with the axioms:
SS1: ...
SS2: ...
SS3: ...
A *distributive system of sides* is a system of sides with:
DSS1: ...
DSS2: ...
A *monotone system of sides* is a distributive system of sides that:
MSS1: ...
```